# Find interesting segment automatically in funnel analysis

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, funnel-plot

This is a feature that I came across in Mixpanel and really enjoy it, but I haven't figure out how to do it myself (so I can use it on some other dataset).

## Use case

I have a funnel (which I defined myself), and looks like this

[image]

For step 1's data, there are many attributes/segments, such as

- user's country
- user's traffic source (where they come from)
- user's device (ios, android, web etc.)
- user's age
- last purchase day (R for RFM)
- purchase frequency and percentile level(F for RFM)
- purchase amount and percentil level(M for RFM)
- shop category preference
- ltv

and many others

The goal is to identify `interesting segments`. For example, maybe the user with ios device has much higher conversion rate than other devices.

## My question

Now, instead of manually group by the funnel's 1st step by device and other each attributes, **can I do it with `loop through` or any algos?** is there any industry best practice for doing this kind of analysis?

---

## Background and resources

Some output from Mixpanel (which is really interesting)

**(1) Time comparison**

[image]

This detects the segment driving the conversion rate change between differet time periods

**(2) Outlier segment**

[image]

Docs can be find here: https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031788492-Find-Interesting-Segments